# Setting value of hidden element in php

Tags: php, html

I have a hidden field in form. On form submit I call a database function to add the inputs to database and return result of query. I wish to set the value returned to hidden field. But when I am not able to assign a value to it

```
<form name="frmAddBook" id="frmAddBook" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="actionResult" id="actionResult">
```

### PHP

```
echo '
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("hello"); 
document.getElementById("actionResult").value=1;
alert("2222222");
alert(document.frmAddBook.getElementById("actionResult").value);
</script>';
```

Comment: i think it much easy for you to use jQuery framework

Comment: @OP can you please rephrase your question? I don't understand what you mean " I wish to set the value returned to hidden field. But when I am not able to assign a value to it".

Comment: I am returning a value from php class function which i want to assign to hidden field.

Comment: did you mean with ajax? you don't show any ajax here.

Comment: Using php to generate javascript to fill in a value in a form that php is already generating in the first place? Talk about redundant.

Comment: @MarcB I always thought redundancy was I good thing ;)

Comment: I am using a database class to add values to db and return 0 or 1 depending on whether addition is successful or not? After getting the value , I want user to be directed to a particular error or success page with customized message.

Answer (score 4):

you need to specify the value of that hidden input field, so if you wanted to do this in PHP it'd look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="actionResult" id="actionResult" value="<?php echo $result; ?>"/>
```